# Dynamic Org-capture Templates

Tags: org-capture

I've read the `org-capture template` documentation and searched for "Dynamic org-capture templates" but cannot seem to find out how to create the following:

```
C-c c
"a"
Activity: math              (<--need completion here)
Topic: multiplication       (<--need completion here)
Date: 2017-09-11            (<--need default to todays date)
Start time: 07:00 AM        (<--need to define AM/PM easily)
Duration: 20                (<--easier way to capture time?)
Unit: mins
```

Whereas if another `Activity` was chosen, the `Options` would be different:

```
C-c c
"a"
Activity: physical education
Type: Yoga
Class: Level 2 flow
Date: 2017-09-11
Start time: 07:00 AM
Duration: 90
Unit: mins
```

Where in an `org-capture-template` can I specify the `Activity` to `Option` mapping?

How can I use completion to make capturing the data quicker?

Comment: Anyone have insights into this?

Comment: WOW! No one has a method for accomplishing this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this can likely be achieved by some elaborate Lisp scheme, you would supposedly still have to manually specify which options go with which activities. Thus, it is probably more simple and maintainable to copy-paste a new capture template for each activity. As capture templates can be grouped logically with two-key selectors (e.g., first press a for "activity", then m for "math"), this solution might be equally good in practice. Add the code below to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote
       (("a" "Activity")
        ("am" "Activity (math)" entry (file+headline "/path/to/file" "Log")
         "Activity: math\nTopic: %^{Topic}\nDate: %u\nStart time: %^{Time}\nDuration: %^{Duration}\nUnit: mins" :immediate-finish)
        ("ap" "Activity (physical education)" entry (file+headline "/path/to/file" "Log")
         "Activity: physical education\nType: %^{Type}\nClass: %^{Class}\nDate: %u\nStart time: %^{Time}\nDuration: %^{Duration}\nUnit: mins" :immediate-finish)
        ("ax" "Activity (other)" entry (file+headline "/path/to/file" "Log")
         "Activity: %^{Activity}\n%?\nDate: %u\nStart time: %^{Time}\nDuration: %^{Duration}\nUnit: mins") )))
```

The resulting menu then looks like this:

[image: Two-key capture template allows logical grouping]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'd really like a way for IDO or Helm to "pick up" on the entries each time and provide completion or add new. Similar to adding a new file in emacs. Searches for whats existing, then adds a new file if none.